# Can I use my SVN as a staging/dev site?

Tags: svn, staging

I currently `SVN` everything to a local *server*. I am aware that everything is compressed down to a *DB-like* format (Berkley?). Is there anyway to leverage my repo as a dev/staging server or am I going to have to go the "old-fashioned" route?

Comment: or you could look at a DVCS like git, mercurial or bazaar.

Comment: @yasouser - How is a DVCS different from SVN for what he is asking or seem to be asking?

Comment: The OP is looking for how to setup svn so that he can play with the code and do interim commits before publishing the work to the rest of the team/public/audience. DVCS provides that facility without any need for extra setup. If you are not familiar with any DVCS see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control. To know the differences in the workflow between svn and say git see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871/why-is-git-better-than-subversion

Comment: @yasouser - I am familiar enough with DVCS's :) He is asking for a server hosting a repo and also having the code on it to serve the app, and a central Git repo on a server would be a bare repo (it is not only a practise, but almost necessary to have the Git repo that people push to to be bare ) and in that context it is same as an SVN repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup a working directory ( checkout ) of the repo on the same server and have a `post-commit` hook setup in it which will update the working directory on every commit.

Comment: Your help led me to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140614/how-can-i-use-post-commit-hooks-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-web-directory-from-s